# Stack Parenthesis Matching in C

Tags: c, data-structures

When I execute this code and debug, I see the "h" between `op1` and `op2` values when I entered two parentheses `()`. I don't know where it came from. Can you help me to solve this problem? It's about data structure without pointers. I don't know where this garbage value comes from.

Problems:

```
op = pop();
printf("op1: %ch\n", op); //() = h
op2 = ch;
printf("op2: %ch\n", op2);
```

Link below which has full of code.
https://paste2.org/yNhFcx5s

Comment: Probably a confusion between `%hc` and `%ch`... Just remove the `h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format specifier for char is %c. the extra h added by you is being printed

Comment: If I turn char to int, can i get paranthesis in stack ?

Comment: You can store the paranthesis in the stack as int or char. char is stored internally as its ASCII equivalent. Only for the sake of displaying it as a parenthesis, you should display it as a char

Answer (score 0):

If `op` and `op2` have type `short int`, the correct code would be:

```
op = pop();
printf("op1: %hc\n", op);
op2 = ch;
printf("op2: %hc\n", op2);
```

and since the type is actually `char`, you might even write:

```
op = pop();
printf("op1: %hhc\n", op);
op2 = ch;
printf("op2: %hhc\n", op2);
```

But you could just use `%c` as `short` and `char` values are promoted to `int` when passed to variadic functions such as `printf()`.